# ElasticSearch: Boolean calculated field on existance of string in other field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get a boolean calculated field for each document returned, which value depends on the existance of a given string in another (multivalued) field of the document.

In Solr I would do this with `query()`, but how is it done in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `_index` with `tf()` as referenced [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "MY_FIELD:TERM"
    }
  },
  "script_fields" : {
    "MY_SCRIPT_FIELD" : {
      "script" : "_index['MY_MULTIVALUED_FIELD']['MY_SEARCH_STRING'].tf()"
    }
  }
}
```

You just have to regard that the returned value is not a boolean but an array with one item which is `0` or `1`. But that can be mapped client side.